# How to Select * FROM table1, table2 correctly when table1 = table2

Tags: sql

There is a table cs_goods_features like this
(id - product id, f - product property name, v - property value)

| id | f | v |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | f1 | 10 |
| 1 | f2 | 15 |
| 1 | f3 | 25 |
| 2 | f1 | 10 |
| 2 | f2 | 15 |
| 2 | f3 | 35 |
| 3 | f1 | 15 |
| 3 | f2 | 10 |
| 3 | f3 | 55 |

I need to select only those products id, which have, for example, f1 = 10 and f2 = 15.

If I make a query like this

```
SELECT id 
  FROM cs_goods_features
  where (f in ('f1', 'f2'))
    and (v in (10,15))
```

then everything is fine except when the table has opposite values - not f1=10 and f2=15, but f1=15 and f2=10. I don't need such lines in result set.

What I need can be done like this:

```
select g1.id, g2.id
   FROM cs_goods_features g1, cs_goods_features g2 
 WHERE g1.f = 'f1'
   and g1.v = 10 
   and g2.f = 'f2'
   and g2.v = 15
```

But the problem here is that I get two columns in the output (and if i need to select products by 3 properties - there would be 3 columns). And I'm not satisfied with it, because actually this query is going to be a subquery in a larger query.

In other words there will be

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tablename
 where ID in (our_query)
```

It means I need exactly one column with results for construction "where ID in (...)" to work correctly

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I use MariaDB database

Comment: If you want f=f1, v=10 and f=f2, v=15 but not the other way around you can check the pairs. `SELECT id FROM cs_goods_features where (f, v) in (('f1', 10), ('f2', 15))` https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iRa2yqZiEwxVefWiYXDENv/0

Comment: This query returns also id where f1=10 and f2 - other value, not 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is by counting for each `id` the number of times (f1, 10) and (f2, 15) appear and selecting `distinct id` where they appear at least once each:

```
select distinct id from
(select *,
sum(case when f = 'f1' and v = 10 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by id) as f1_10,
sum(case when f = 'f2' and v = 15 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by id) as f2_15
from cs_goods_features) t
where f1_10 > 0 and f2_15 > 0
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=94b87fb33c50c0776d7dcf496938d3ec)

Comment: I doubt the result will be the expected one (ex: v=15 row will be returned)

Comment: I read the question again, apparently the OP wants to get the ids only as per my understanding.

Comment: OK sorry, it's me that did not understand properly =)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just separate into 2 groups like below:

```sql
SELECT id
  FROM cs_goods_features
 WHERE (f = 'f1' AND v = 10)
    OR (f = 'f2' AND v = 15)
```

Comment: With such query in result set will be products which have for example only f1=10 and f2 - not 15, but  other value. I need products with both conditions - f1 = 10 and f2=15

Comment: ah yes, you're right. Sorry for not reading the question carefully ;)